# Return all entries in groups where a group member satisfies condition x

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

In Ms Access, I'm trying to write a SQL query that answers a question like:
Return all player IDs on all teams in a list of football players where at least one member of the team is injured.

I'm new to SQL. I've tried something like

```
SELECT pid FROM players WHERE team_id IN 
           (SELECT team_id FROM players WHERE injury = 'yes')
```

Access won't accept this IN. Is there a simple way to do this? I'd rather run thus as one query, instead of creating separate queries, so I can change it easily as necessary.

Comment: That is valid MS Access SQL. Are you sure injury is text and not YesNo data type? For yesno, you should say `SELECT team_id FROM players WHERE injury = true`,  you should test the subquery to make sure it works.

Comment: Tried again and you're right, thanks! If there's a better way to write this I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that it doesn't support `IN`, nevertheless you can do it using a join:

```
SELECT distinct players.pid
FROM players as injured
INNER JOIN players on players.team_id = injured.team_id
WHERE injured.injury = 'yes'
```

I used `distinct` in case there's multiple injured players on the one team, which would result in the players from that team being returned multiple times

Comment: Does there even need to be a join? Why not a simple select with a simple where clause for injury='yes'

Comment: @Ric yes there needs to be a join. re-read the question: "all players from teams that have injured players". do it on paper and you'll get a better feel for it

Comment: Access SQL does support IN, but you must specify a JOIN type. Also, `players injured` won't work.

Comment: @Bohemian yeah might be better off writing it down as per your suggestion. Just didn't feel write at first!!

Comment: Do I need to have 2 tables to use JOIN, or can I do this with just one?

Comment: @Remou why won't it work? "injured" is the alias for "players" table at that point. Doesn't MS Access support this syntax? Or do I need "as" in there?

Comment: Sry, I did not read the alias right. That is fine, but you will need a join type.

Comment: @Remou OK cool. Thanks - I didn't know that (most databases assume `inner` join type if not specified). I threw an "as" in there too for good measure :)

Comment: @nrflaw A join has to be between two tables, but they can be two instances of the same table. If such a self join is done, at least one of the table instances must be given an alias as is done in Bohemian's answer.